# Can we use outlook file type(.oft) template and send email using smtp mail server?

Tags: c#, outlook, smtp

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Application.CreateItemFromTemplate

Is It possible to use above reference but send email using other smtp server ?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not looking for any concrete answer here. I have went through several articles and on code projects it says It is not possible therefor I am just trying to be sure and if it is possible than I am looking from export for right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using MsgReader library(Install-Package MSGReader -Version 3.7.3)

Here is solution which works for me.

```
using (var msg = new MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message(@"C:\\test.oft"))
            {
                var from = msg.Sender;
                var sentOn = msg.SentOn;
                var recipientsTo = msg.GetEmailRecipients(MsgReader.Outlook.RecipientType.To, false, false);
                var recipientsCc = msg.GetEmailRecipients(MsgReader.Outlook.RecipientType.Cc, false, false);
                var subject = msg.Subject;
                var htmlBody = msg.BodyHtml;
                var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("^^service account email^^", "^^service account password^^"),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
                var mailMessage = new MailMessage()
                {
                    From = new MailAddress("^^from email^^"),
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = htmlBody,
                    IsBodyHtml = true,
                    Priority = MailPriority.Normal
                };
                mailMessage.To.Add("^^to email^^");
                client.Send(mailMessage);
            }
```

**Note:** Solution doesn't need any outlook application to be installed and no dialog/popup.

Helpful links:

```
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?538563-Read-Outlook-Email-Template-(-OFT)-File-and-Save-Message-as-MSG-Format-in-C
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633082/read-outlook-msg-file
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19571/MsgReader-DLL
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have multiple accounts configured in Outlook (including an smtp mail server) you can use the [SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which allows setting an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent.

```
Sub SendUsingAccount()  
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts  
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then  
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account"  
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com")  
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll  
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount  
     oMail.Send  
   End If 
 Next  
End Sub
```

You may find the following articles helpful:

[How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)

[How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)

[How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)

Comment: While this answer may or may not help OP (the question is simply too unclear to estimate that), it´s definitly written in the whrong language.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene but our smpt server is not part of Outlook.

Comment: Why do you need to use Outlook's [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) then?

Comment: Our requirement is for different client there could be different email template and It is quite easy to create outlook email template also If our email template contains any image than I don't need create a CDN link of same image. Hope I am able to explain.

Comment: You just need to configure an SMTP account in Outlook and your task will be solved easily.