# how to convert .msg file into Exchange.EmailMessage object in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-restapi

I need to open and convert a .msg file from disk into Exchange EmailMessage object in order to iterate it and do some operations. It can be possibile? I cannot find something useful on internet.

There's a way?

I tried with this library MsgReader.Outlook to open it, but I cannot convert it to Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.

Comment: If you don't absolutely need an `EmailMessage` object but just need the contents, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633082

Comment: Are you trying to insert a new or completely replace the contents of an existing Exchange message with the contents of an MSG file? Or just reset some properties?

Comment: I need to test how the code works, but for reasons I cannot access the Exchange server for debug, so I'm trying to use a email .msg file.
For that reason I need to convert the file to EmailMessage object to understand what's inside the object